# Lucene Indexing to ignore apostrophes

Tags: lucene

I have a field that might have apostrophes in it.
I want to be able to:
1. store the value as is in the index
2. search based on the value ignoring any apostrophes.

I am thinking of using:

```
   doc.add(new Field("name", value, Store.YES, Index.NO));
   doc.add(new Field("name", value.replaceAll("['‘’`]",""), Store.NO, Index.ANALYZED));
```

if I then do the same replace when searching I guess it should work and use the cleared value to index/search and the value as is for display.

am I missing any other considerations here ?

Answer (score 0):

Performing `replaceAll` directly on the value its a bad practice in Lucene, since it would a much better practice to encapsulate your tokenization recipe in an `Analyzer`. Also I don't see the benefit of appending fields in your use case (See [Document.add](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add%28org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable%29)).

If you want to Store the original value and yet be able to search without the apostrophes simply declare your field like this:

```
doc.add(new Field("name", value, Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED);
```

Then simply hook up a custom `Tokenizer` that will replace apostrophes (I think the Lucene's `StandardAnalyzer` already includes this transformation).

If you are storing the field with the aim of using highlighting you should also consider using `Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS`.

Comment: Thanks jspboix, Where and how should I hook up the custom Tokenizer ? Do I need a Tokenizer or an Analizer?

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is probably the right way to go. As for myself I ended up with the two `.add` calls as described in the Q.