# Lucene: dealing with apostrophe

Tags: java, lucene, apostrophe

I would like to deal with apostrophes in Lucene. Let's give an example. I have the following sentence : "L'arbre est vert". I would like to know how can I create a query on the word "arbre" 'without the apostrophe). With the StandardAnalyzer I need to write "L'arbre" to have a positive answer.

Note that there is one question here : [Lucene Indexing to ignore apostrophes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309527/lucene-indexing-to-ignore-apostrophes). But as I am quite new in Lucene I would like to have an example (code snippet that works in Lucene 5.3).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need something with more robust analysis of the French language.  I would consider using [FrenchAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fr/FrenchAnalyzer.html).  StandardAnalyzer is designed to provide a passable language-agnostic analysis.  If you want more intelligent linguistic analysis of a particular language, you should look to the analyzer for that language.

For "L'arbre est vert", StandardAnalyzer tokenizes it into:

- l'arbre
- est
- vert

Where FrenchAnalyzer gives you:

- arbr
- vert

Comment: The problem is that I have to index multi languages. Not only french. So this solution doesn't fit my use case. For instance in english we can have "a woman's hat". I would like that the query "woman" give me a positive answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @femtoRgon you need to address this need with more appropriate analysis. You can either change the analyzer of a field depending on the language of a particular document/query, or you can choose a more advanced strategy as using language specific indices or fields.

Have a look at [Multilingual Search using Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280368/multilingual-search-using-lucene/34620738#34620738) for an overview of the possible strategies.